# Passing data via a routerLink angular router template expression?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-router

Playing around with the stackblitz starting point and I added the following routing:

```
    const routes : Routes = [ {path: 'hello', 'component': HelloComponent}];


    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ 
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true}) ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
    })
```

Also added a `<router-outlet>` to the `app-component.html` template, and the `hello-component` is rendered when the below link is clicked:

```
<a routerLink="hello" routerLinkActive="active">hello</a>
```

However the property on the `hello-component` component is empty when the link is clicked:

```
@Input() name: string;
```

Is there a way to pass in a value via a template expression such that the name property is set on the component and is evaluated in the `hello-component.ts`'s template string with the `hello` anchor is clicked?

Just for reference the hello component looks like this:

```
    import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'hello',
      template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
      styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
    })
    export class HelloComponent  {
      @Input() name: string;
    }
```

It seems like perhaps an `ActivatedRoute` instance has to be examined for for a property for this to work?

Comment: Where do you want to set the value? In the  routes array, or do you want to pass the value within the URL as a URL parameter? At the moment I don't see where you're passing any value in

Comment: Via the router link in a dynamic expression .... so instead of routerLink="hello"  ... routerLink="dynamic expression here ...."

Comment: Okay, can you please add the link to your stackblitz? Thanks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnbuyb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, amend your route definition to allow a path parameter, like so:

```
const routes : Routes = [ 
  {path: 'crisis-center', 'component': HelloComponent}, 
  {path: 'hello/:name', 'component': HelloComponent}, 
  {path: '**', 'component': HelloComponent}
];
```

This will allow you to pass a `name` parameter to the `/hello` route.

To access it within the component, you need to subscribe to the paramter changes, like so:

```
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe( params =>
        this.name = params.get('name')
    )
  }
}
```

And finally, you can then pass a value in via the `routerLink`, like so:

```
<a [routerLink]="['hello', routeOneName]" routerLinkActive="active">hello</a>
```

Where `routeOneName` is a variable declared in `AppComponent`.

I've created a fork of your StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqt4jy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) if you'd like to look

Comment: Also notice that there are [] around routerLink.  Is that because we are assigning an array instead of a string like "hello"

Comment: @Ole The brackets around `[routerLink]` tells Angular that the bit after the `=` should be treated as code, not just as a string. The brackets around `['hello', routeOneName]` is because that's an array, where the first element is the path, and the second element is the value you want to pass. If we excluded the brackets around `[routerLink]`, this would no longer be treated as an array, just a string

Comment: for some reason, this is not working out for me. esp to pass some values over as a json.
the code am trying is this: [routerLink]="['/pages/somepage',{ somekey1:1234 , key2:12345}]"